# Why doesn’t this solution to the hat matching problem work?

Tags: probability, derangements

I am trying to understand why this solution to a specific case of the hat matching problem is incorrect.

The problem goes like this: $n$ professors each place their hat for a total $n$ hats into a bag. The professors each randomly select a hat. What is the probability that none of the professors receive their own hat?

Can we not interpret each draw by a professor as a single independent event? As in, the probability we have for the first professor drawing a hat other than his hat is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Continuing on with successive independent events where there is one less hat and one less professor leads to the probability that no professor draws their own hat: $P(\text{no match}) = \frac{n-1}{n} * \frac{n-2}{n-1} * \frac{n-3}{n-2} * \dots * \frac{1}{2} * 1$. The reasoning for the last item being that there is only one hat left for the last professor to draw.

Can someone explain where my logic is flawed?

Comment: Suppose there were only 2 professors. You then want the first professor to not get his own hat. Agreed that has likelihood (2-1)/2=1/2. But the success of that first professor's draw is far from independent from the second professor's draw. Because once the first hat is taken there is only one hat left for the second professor to choose. And in this case that is not his hat. [It is the first professors hat.]

Comment: The probability professor 2 (out of n) does not get his own hat is not necessarily $(n-2)/(n-1)$. If professor 1 took professor 2's hat then it would be $(n-1)/(n-1)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement even uses the specific example of hats to go through the problem.

Comment: In addition to above comments, each of your terms is supposed to be the probability that the $i^{\text{th}}$ person doesn't pick their hat. But how in that case could the last term be 1? The probability that the last professor picks his own hat is clearly not 0.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. They helped me gain a deeper appreciation for the problem. Specifically, the derangement reference was really enlightening.